# What LONGTEXT occupy in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Does LONGTEXT occupy the amount of characters you store, or occupy the max of length 4G in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occupies just the amount of space it needs. (It would be a little crazy if all `LONGTEXT` entries took up 4GB of space!)

Note that these columns aren't part of the row data. The column essentially stores a pointer to an external file containing the data. So the row itself isn't huge, even if the data in that column is huge.